# How do you rearrange the terms of a lower and upper Darboux sum to yield another inequality?

Tags: calculus, analysis

It is known :

$L(f,P) \leq \int_{a*}^{b}f \leq \int_{a}^{b*} f\leq U(f,P)$

where

$\int_{a*}^{b}f$ is the lower integral

$\int_{a}^{b*}f$ is the upper integral

$L(f,P) $ is the lower Darboux sum of $f$ with partition $P$

$U(f,P) $ is the lower Darboux sum of $f$ with partition $P$

How is it possible to conclude :

$0 \leq \int_{a}^{b*} f-\int_{a*}^{b}f \leq U(f,P) - L(f,P)$

??

I tried to do simple algebra but I'm not getting the exact inequality above.

Comment: $A\leq B\leq C\leq D$ Then $$ 0\leq C-B $$ and $$ (C-B)-(A-D)=(C-A) + (D-B) \geq 0 $$

Comment: Any two points in the interval $[a,b]$ are at most $b-a$ apart.